# How to change passwords using PHP

Tags: php, passwords

I want to allow users to change their password and their password is stored in a file called user_data.txt. How can I allow them to edit their password using solely php? I do not use have MySQL or Java.. just PHP.. This is the code that I have for verifying login.

```
if ($username  == $users[$x]['username'] &&  $_POST['password'] == $users[$x]['password']){
    $name = $_POST['username'];

 /////this is the code to read the file

    $userdata = "user_data.txt";
    function arrayfile_to_array($filepath){
        $fsize = filesize($filepath);
        if ($fsize > 0) {
            $fp = fopen($filepath, "r");
            $encoded = fread($fp, $fsize);
            fclose($fp);
            return unserialize($encoded);
        }
    }
}
```

this is the code to save the information into $users variable

```
$users = arrayfile_to_array ($userdata);
```

Basically I will be creating an account page that allows them to change their password.

Thank you!

Comment: switch to MySQL. that would make your life 10 times easier.

Comment: Make that about 20x. It's more practical to store user information in a database rather than a normal `.txt` file. Make sure you are hashing the passwords in something like SHA256 when storing them, too. That would be a bad move (for the user) to store their passwords as plain text. Hashing the same password will always return the same end hash, so it's just an extra layer of security.

Comment: I agree. also. setting up a MySQL database might look scary at first but there are many great examples out there on how to do it. It's easier than you think.

Comment: @TyQ.On the contrary, simply hashing a password is not considered secure, because rainbow tables can be used to find the clear-text version of the hashed passwords. A password should be hashed using a salt, and PHP provides the `password_hash()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function specifically for that purpose.

Comment: If you use another function then I would solve this.

Comment: Hi guys, I don't have a MySQL license